# What's the best practice for creating instances of a struct?

Tags: struct, rust

I'm trying to understand what's the best practice for creating instances of a `struct`. In C++ I'd pass everything I need to the constructor and throw an exception if the `struct` could not be created. In rust I've been told to create a method that returns a `Result`. But isn't this too much work? Why not just `fail!()`?

Also, if returning `Result` is the way to go, does this mean that all structs will need a factory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A basic constructor for `YourStruct` should be a static method called `YourStruct::new()` (see the [Rust style guidelines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/ownership/constructors.html) for more info).

For the return type, use `YourStruct` if nothing can go wrong or if you use `fail!()`. Use `Option<YourStruct>` if there's only one obvious reason for the constructor failing. Use `Result<YourStruct, YourStructErr>` if it would be helpful to the caller to know why it failed. The problem with `fail!()` is it doesn't give the caller a chance to try again, or pass a nice error message back to the user, or whatever else the caller might want to do. In certain situations, `fail!()` might be okay.